# MyFirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived() does not work

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity

I am trying to "catch" firebase cloud messages sent to the app, and when I recieve(/click) one I want to execute something based on the "Custom data" key/value added in the firebase console.

My code right now looks like this:

**MyFirebaseMessagingService:**

```
package com.company.app;

import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import java.util.Map;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "Notification";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        Log.i(TAG, "Receiving notification...");
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : remoteMessage.getData().entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            String value = entry.getValue();
            Log.d(TAG, "key, " + key + " value " + value);
        }
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
        ...

        <!-- Firebase notification -->
        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>
```

**build.gradle (Module:app):**

```
dependencies {

    //Google firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.1'

    ...
```

My guess is that `<service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService" android:exported="false">` is not being executed, but I can't figure out why. 
I am not getting any errors.
Other than this my notifications work without any issues.

Here's the console log if that's of any assisstance:

```
D/FA: Logging event (FE): notification_receive(_nr), 
Bundle[{
 ga_event_origin(_o)=fcm,
 message_device_time(_ndt)=0,
 message_type(_nmc)=display,
 message_name(_nmn)=B1 - TN18,
 message_time(_nmt)=1574177464,
 message_id(_nmid)=8950284200210511319}]
```

Any ideas?

Edit: the same code works in an otherwise empty app

Edit 2: problem is somehow caused by google's TWA LauncherActivity

Edit 3:

```
public class LauncherActivityTWA extends AppCompatActivity {

private TwaLauncher mTwaLauncher;
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    this.mTwaLauncher.launch(getLaunchingUrl()); //this is causing the issue
}
```

Edit 4: for now I have solved this by switching over to WebView, I will try to get it working with TWA later. I still think this issue is somehow caused by TWA or some libraries associated with it

Edit 5: So I found a kind of a workaround - if you want to keep using TWA and FCM at the same time you'll have to work with Data Messages only, Notification Messages don't seem to trigger `onMessageReceived` even when app is in foreground

Comment: if your onMessageReceived method not working it might be because of notification class in notification response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem only occurs when the received message is a notification message. It works as expected with data messages, even with TWA. More info about message types [here.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive)

> TL;DR: data messsages trigger the even always, notification messages only when app is in foreground.

I don't know what's causing this issue, but I've already created an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/989) about it, so maybe it'll get fixed in the future.

Comment: How can I "catch" a notification even when the app is in background because I would like to send a list of notifications in Data property to schedualle notifications for 1-2 day at a time

Answer (score 0):

[From your question, I can guess you are receiving Data Message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options)

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    if (remoteMessage == null)
        return;
    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }
    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        String title = "", body = "", type = "";
        Intent hIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomePageActivity.class);
        try {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : remoteMessage.getData().entrySet()) 
               {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                String value = entry.getValue();
                CommonUtils.logThis(TAG, "key, " + key + " value " + value);
                switch (key) {
                    case "title":
                        title = entry.getValue();
                        break;
                    case "body":
                        body = entry.getValue();
                        break;
                    case "type":
                        type = entry.getValue().toLowerCase();
                        break;
                }
            }
            CommonUtils.logThis("jeev", "Type is : " + type);
            switch (type) {
                case "your_notification_type":
                    //write your code here
                    break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            CommonUtils.logThis(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From what I understand, no. I remember reading you can only send Notification Messages from the firebase console, no?

Comment: No, it can be sent via backend code. Firebase console is just for testing, real logic can be written in the backend. So that you can send notification on any particular API call.

Comment: The onMessageRecieved is still not being called, I think the issue isn't in the method itself. Though your code looks like it's what I need.

Answer (score 0):

**app build.gradle**

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'here
```

**Menifest.xml**

```
 <service android:name=".Notification.MyFirebaseInstanceIdService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name=".Notification.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/app_icon" />
```

**MyFirebaseMessagingService.Java**

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

```
private static final String TAG = "notifi";
NotificationChannel mChannel;
String CHANNEL_ID="1234";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);




    Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "Name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        mChannel.setLightColor(Color.GRAY);
        mChannel.enableLights(true);
        mChannel.enableVibration(true);
        mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500});
        mChannel.setDescription("desc");
        AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                .build();
        mChannel.setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI, audioAttributes);
        if (notificationManager != null) {
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel( mChannel );
        }
    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("MY Notification");
    notificationBuilder.setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon);

    //Vibration
    notificationBuilder.setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 });
    //LED
    notificationBuilder.setLights(Color.RED, 3000, 3000);

    //Ton
    notificationBuilder.setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);

    notificationBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    notificationManager.notify(0,notificationBuilder.build());







}


private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage.Notification notification, Map<String, String> data) {
    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channel_id")
            .setContentTitle(notification.getTitle())
            .setContentText(notification.getBody())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setContentInfo(notification.getTitle())
            .setLargeIcon(icon)
            .setColor(Color.RED)
            .setLights(Color.RED, 1000, 300)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);


    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Notification Channel is required for Android O and above
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("channel_id", "channel_name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        channel.setDescription("channel description");
        channel.setShowBadge(true);
        channel.canShowBadge();
        channel.enableLights(true);

        channel.setLightColor(Color.WHITE);
        channel.enableVibration(true);
        channel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500});
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

    }

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());

   }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Manifest.xml

```
  <service
        android:name=".FirebaseNotification.FirebaseIDService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".FirebaseNotification.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

FirebaseMessagingService class

```
 @Override
 public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

  // if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
  // sendUserNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"), r . 
  //emoteMessage.getData().get("text"));
  //}

    JSONObject json = null;
    try {
        json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
        //Log.e("JSON OBJECT", object.toString());
        JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");
        String titel = data.getString("title");
        String message = data.getString("message");
        String image = data.getString("image");
        sendUserNotification(titel, message,image);
        //rest of the code
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}


private void sendUserNotification(String title, String mess,String image) {
    Log.e("JSON title", title);
    Log.e("JSON mess", mess);
    int notifyID = 1;
    Intent intent;
    NotificationChannel mChannel;


    NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle bpStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
    //bpStyle.bigPicture(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.fastfood)).build();
    bpStyle.bigPicture(getBitmapfromurl(image));


    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    intent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    String CHANNEL_ID = context.getPackageName();// The id of the channel.
    CharSequence name = "Sample one";// The user-visible name of the channel.
    int importance = 0;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
    }
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID);
    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    notificationBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
    notificationBuilder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    notificationBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(mess));
    notificationBuilder.setContentText(mess);
    notificationBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon(notificationBuilder));
    notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    notificationBuilder.setStyle(bpStyle);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    }
    if (notificationManager != null) {
        notificationManager.notify(notifyID /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }


}



 public class FirebaseIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
 private static final String TAG = "FirebaseIDService";
 public static final String FIREBASE_TOKEN = "token";


@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    //System.out.println("token=================="+refreshedToken);
    Log.i(TAG, "FCM Registration Token: " + refreshedToken);
    SharedPrefUtil.getInstance(this).put(FIREBASE_TOKEN,refreshedToken);

}

}
```

Comment: `FirebaseInstanceIdService`, which I'm assuming is the superclass of `.FirebaseNotification.FirebaseIDService` is deprecated and should be replaced with overriding `onNewToken` from `FirebaseMessagingService`. Also, can I see your main activity, please?

Comment: Are you received the firebase generated token key or not.

Comment: I am receiving it, but I'm using `onNewToken`

Comment: In starting activity  you just call   FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());

Comment: Also i have shared the FirebaseIDService code check once .All the best

Comment: A) FirebaseInstanceIdService is deprecated and should NOT be used. B) My problem is not with the token

Comment: I am not implement anything in activity class just i have used in my fragment   predefined method FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getContext()); inside on create and then receiving key from FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()); at last store the key in my database.what is your problem please explain clearly .

Comment: I've already explained it in the issue. The problem with notifications is caused by Google's TWA, which I was using. That's why I asked to see your main activity. I've already created an issue on Firebase github: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/989